# Event ID 9331 MSExchangeSA & Event ID 9335 MSExchangeSA

Tags: windows, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

I get this two Exchange 2010 Global Address book related event IDs:

**Event ID 9331 MSExchangeSA**

> OABGen encountered error 80004005 (internal ID 50101f1) accessing the
>   public folder database while generating the offline address list for
>   address list '/'.
>
> -\Default Offline Address List

and

**Event ID 9335 MSExchangeSA**

> OABGen encountered error 80004005 while cleaning the offline address
>   list public folders under /o=xxxxx
>   xxxx/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address List.  Please
>   make sure the public folder database is mounted and replicas exist of
>   the offline address list folders.  No offline address lists have been
>   generated.  Please check the event log for more information.
>
> -\Default Offline Address List

It is Exchange 2010 SP2 sitting on Windows 2008 enterprise edition.

Essentially the issue is that the global address book is not being updated on Outlook clients.  We are using Outlook 2007 and 2010.

So far I have tried running the following command:

```
Update-FileDistributionService -Identity ExchangeServer -Type "OAB"
```

And I tried this solution as well:

> 1) Make sure the Microsoft Exchange System Attendant is running. It
>   will be set to start automatically by default, but it doesn't. This is
>   a known issue. Start this service manually. When running, you will not
>   get an error when trying to update the GAL.
>
> 2) "Apply" any changes made to any address lists before the GAL will
>   update Outlook properly. In Organization Configuration -> Mailbox in
>   EMC, view the properties of the Default Global Address Book in the
>   Offline Address Book tab. In the properties window, select the Address
>   Lists tab. This shows which address lists makes up the GAL.
>
> 3) Close the properties window and select the Address Lists tab in the
>   Organization Configuration -> Mailbox. Right-click each address list
>   used by the Def GAL and click "Apply" (make sure the "Immediately"
>   radio button is checked).
>
> 4) Last, go back to the Offline Address Book tab, right-click the GAL
>   and select "Update".
>
> After a few send/receives in the Outlook clients, their Glogal Address
>   List should update to show the latest changes.

Neither one of those solutions helped.  So I am not really sure what to do here.  Also, I am aware of changing registry on each local computers, but it would be close to impossible as we have 8 offices in 3 different countries.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 7.XII.2012 @ 10.35**

I forgot to mention that we did rebuild the address book and that didn't help.

**EDIT 27.III.2013 @ 17.15**

Well, after running

> Get-PublicFolder "\non_ipm_subtree\offline address 
>   book/o=ORG/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address list"
>   -Recurse |  Set-PublicFolder -Replicas "second storage group\public folder database"

I get the following error:

[image]

When I execute **Get-PublicFolder**, all I get is **IPM_SUBTREE**.  I tried substituting the non_ipm_subtree with ipm_subtree to no luck...

Still need help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your system event log. I got the exact same error on a system that was reporting read errors for the log drive.

Comment: That's where I got the errors from.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the PF Store on the E2K7 box as a replica for the OAB folders. Need to run these commands for that:

```
Get-PublicFolder "\non_ipm_subtree\offline address 
book\/o=ORG/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address list" -Recurse | 
Set-PublicFolder -Replicas "second storage group\public folder database"


Get-PublicFolder "\non_ipm_subtree\offline address 
book\/o=ORG/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address List" -Recurse | 
Set-PublicFolder -ReplicationSchedule $alwaysrun

Here /o=ORG, ORG represents the name of the Exchange Organization.
```

Also, the "second storage group\public folder database" represents the name of the public folder database. By default this would be second storage group\Public folder database.

Comment: Well, even though from all of my research that is a correct answer, it's still didn't work.  See about for another edit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem today, was a missing replication entry

[Event ID 9335 and 9331 Offline Address Book Update Errors](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000849.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! Can you add relevant snippets to your answer from the article?  We discourage just posting links as links tend to change and create link rot, thus rendering answers such as this useless.

Comment: 6 years later and my link still works :)

Comment: Hahaha, nice.  :)