# Global Address List and OAB issues with Microsoft Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, exchange

The previous network admin moved everything over from Exchange 2003 to exchange 2010.  Ever since that was done, neither the global address book nor offline address book list any of the new users that have been created since that migration.  I went into Organization Configuration mailbox and tried to update the offline address book and got this error:

> Failed to generate the content of the offline address book 'default offline address list'. two possible reasons for the failure are that the system attendant service is not running or you do not have permission to perform this operation.

What is really strange about this issue is that the GAL works fine on OWA.

Comment: What version of Outlook are your clients running?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is no longer answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and this solution worked for me:

You need to add the PF Store on the E2K7 box as a replica for the OAB folders. Need to run these commands for that:

```
Get-PublicFolder "\non_ipm_subtree\offline address 
book\/o=ORG/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address list" -Recurse | 
Set-PublicFolder -Replicas "second storage group\public folder database"


Get-PublicFolder "\non_ipm_subtree\offline address 
book\/o=ORG/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address List" -Recurse | 
Set-PublicFolder -ReplicationSchedule $alwaysrun

Here /o=ORG, ORG represents the name of the Exchange Organization.
```

Also, the "second storage group\public folder database" represents the name of the public folder database. By default this would be second storage group\Public folder database.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/455842/event-id-9331-msexchangesa-event-id-9335-msexchangesa)

Hopefully this helps!